# Sendgrid email always being sent to gmail spam

Tags: email, gmail, sendgrid, spam, email-delivery

I have a clickfunnel account using sendgrid for smtp.  The email being sent are all ending up in GMAILs SPAM inbox.  The emails are text that contain a link to a pdf that was requested via an opt-in form from a clickfunnels website  This doesnt seem to happen for any other provider.  Can someone provide any input/help?  Below is my header .

```
Delivered-To: skaterproig+30@gmail.com
Received: by 10.64.55.101 with SMTP id r5csp284677iep;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2017 09:22:37 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.107.136.90 with SMTP id k87mr3674950iod.34.1485451357582;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2017 09:22:37 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <bounces+4613786-5cd9-skaterproig+30=gmail.com@default.dojo360marketing.com>
Received: from o1.0qt.s2shared.sendgrid.net (o1.0qt.s2shared.sendgrid.net. [167.89.106.58])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id g88si2422968ioj.172.2017.01.26.09.22.36
        for <skaterproig+30@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 26 Jan 2017 09:22:37 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces+4613786-5cd9-skaterproig+30=gmail.com@default.dojo360marketing.com designates 167.89.106.58 as permitted sender) client-ip=167.89.106.58;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@dojo360marketing.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sendgrid.info;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+4613786-5cd9-skaterproig+30=gmail.com@default.dojo360marketing.com designates 167.89.106.58 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=bounces+4613786-5cd9-skaterproig+30=gmail.com@default.dojo360marketing.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=dojo360marketing.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=dojo360marketing.com; h=from:to:subject:mime-version:content-type:content-transfer-encoding:list-unsubscribe; s=s1; bh=iGGvgybvMIwWj8iMo6RNOZBw1oY=; b=NbCSUFZ1IkB2g9M9DkNECSi mplw6GnKswSmceyVOgyIpxnhi2JmWu54GK/UnJ7dUzvDDLu3rKX74pEEzc93su8J uoFpeIowJAINQLXPLTb7UGf7NYXLVfu6nbQK0x+77gusaXyFw2R1MGn5OlW1HWOu z6SM8rDvm8QYMybisXSY=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=sendgrid.info; h=from:to:subject:mime-version:content-type:content-transfer-encoding:list-unsubscribe:x-feedback-id; s=smtpapi; bh=iGGvgybvMIwWj8iMo6RNOZBw1oY=; b=YREBbFAZ8NjnomRX0A SphSIGBUUGZun9eqdHcx7jDqb/VPeHcJx1uUx5iMQw1IfZopgqGWnzVU30szry31 itq/oz1lua6PZCLDtv4afBohZC/mg6L+he6rCAf6+RVOyoBM6SjVwcwP9xE2P3kI jfOStYID8mMXT1/JHXd9i4OjA=
Received: by filter0471p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter0471p1mdw1-4686-588A3057-73
        2017-01-26 17:22:31.905529583 +0000 UTC
Received: from sendgrid.net (ec2-54-159-33-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.159.33.237]) by ismtpd0002p1iad1.sendgrid.net (SG) with ESMTP id mHB920fHRbudUGhPRYyQ8A for <skaterproig+30@gmail.com>; Thu, 26 Jan 2017 17:22:31.849 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2017 17:22:31 +0000
From: Luke <luke@dojo360marketing.com>
To: skaterproig+30@gmail.com
Message-ID: <588a3057c3a82_33fa15953ca98128097b@9d2e634e-4341-4613-b981-ee67318af792.mail>
Subject: Your 7 Strategies For Success On Instagram
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-SG-EID: boxWIquxfC9y+HfUv+zESdBuM+kKU9o0vblHJUWzwP87H0fm+OzTtulmItYBlzjoUqeGCjyRPSVOx+ QXSfpfbKRl9DLuhwM1rzyX5r3GYFOj6X2ZXNdHE5cjqN9KKM7BnX/ZqAWJ9MQH3AuuoJQgsjx1dGxZ Daa06Puh2Pn2FtpkKDBfStHfDn1BbdypuCL4cBqyl9P5qng+q4+VZ0fryhGu8MzUJwtVJOJy8WAbm9 w=
X-Feedback-ID: 4613786:1478j/Xy9kCQOFry+4ViOpy/RBGrksR9BrnnaWgApCk=:1478j/Xy9kCQOFry+4ViOpy/RBGrksR9BrnnaWgApCk=:SG
List-Unsubscribe: <https://u4613786.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/unsubscribe?upn=fuN86yABfSSa-2BXtYbx1pLOyPFfL0-2F84WkGPxC3DB-2FfsqwyzsATyn9L4DfaqnREO823WTcoVlNOJAoTrrzI7TidU5xoxP1SLdTaSgxPYA7cZq2a6Ch9yA27WykpBKh2VKXWWOI0O0WdHdIl8BrtM-2FeZ5KcC3KQFgxwkx-2FlDiXg1oRE34vj0ufecskczVUX5bDimQPtsCC7hVwUO3cjqS06a-2FJ-2BeXDy8BU5pTR2mK1hh4-3D>, <mailto:unsubscribe@default.dojo360marketing.com?subject=https://u4613786.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/unsubscribe*q*upn=fuN86yABfSSa-2BXtYbx1pLOyPFfL0-2F84WkGPxC3DB-2FfsqwyzsATyn9L4DfaqnREO823WTcoVlNOJAoTrrzI7TidU5xoxP1SLdTaSgxPYA7cZq2a6Ch9yA27WykpBKh2VKXWWOI0O0WdHdIl8BrtM-2FeZ5KcC3KQFgxwkx-2FlDiXg1oRE34vj0ufecskczVUX5bDimQPtsCC7hVwUO3cjqS06a-2FJ-2BeXDy8BU5pTR2mK1hh4-3D>
```

Answer (score 18):

Based on [senderscore.org](https://senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=167.89.106.58&validLookup=true), a free IP reputation service from ReturnPath, your IP address has a low reputation score of 78. When your reputation score is that low, Gmail and other mailbox services will automatically route your emails to the spam folder.

The primary reason is that too many users are reporting emails as spam.

In addition, it also appears that you may be on a shared IP, as it looks like many different domains are sending emails from that IP. (That means that your inbox delivery may be impacted by the behavior of other companies.)

In other words, the problem isn't technical in nature, it's related to your email-marketing practices. Your marketing department may be purchasing lists, scraping email addresses from websites and otherwise mailing users without their permission.

Answer (score 4):

This has very little to do with your email marketing practices if you are using sendgrid.  The problem is that as a sender, they are already tainted by every other user of their services.  I ran the senderscore on them and pulled a 51.

(I am currently attempting to implement their services in my node app, so I Pulled the IP they used to send my test email, which of course went to spam.)

THEIR score is a 51, due to very high volume sender.  It has nothing to do with YOUR own personal IP address, since the email is originating from their server and not yours.

I am on this question because I am having this same exact issue right now.  I assume any other mass email service will have the same issue.  I am not sure yet, but I may just use [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/smtp-server)
.  I have not decided since this is not core functionality on my app.  I can update if I make a decision to let you know how it works out. Using nodemailer means that My reputation is only linked to my own server or any other servers operating from that IP.  It's a better chance.  Plus you don't have to pay 10 bucks a month for a reasonable use limit.

Answer (score 3):

Is your sender computer date and time up to date? It may happened  for date and time difference between your computer and the mail server